# Google Glass touchpad input via Android app?

Tags: java, android, google-glass

I have an Android app I will be porting to Google Glass.

How do I programmatically grab the touchpad input (touching side of frame with fingers) in my Android/Java code?

Answer (score 0):

Am I wrong or the API offered by Google are limited to build web app as "services"?

As far as I understood you can just define a bunch of items/functions handled by HTTP request, so you probably want to define a [menu-item](https://developers.google.com/glass/menu-items) that the user will trigger. At this point your server will receive the information with a menu id, so you can understand what to do.

By the way my experience is very vague, unfortunately I don't have Glass (I really wish).. : (

**EDIT:**

As you said seems possible to run native apps (http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/05/07/running-native-android-apps-on-google-glass-ingress-and-other-stuff-video/) but seems very painful to me, and quite "hacky". As the article says: "the Glass touchpad sends Tab and Shift+Tab, not up and down." so you have probably to intercept those inputs.

Btw, notice the battery in this mode: 6 minutes.......

Comment: You can run native Android on glass. But I'm not sure how one would capture the touchpad input.

Comment: When was a native SDK announced?